# Where is IHttpControllerFactory?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Microsoft website says there is a [IHttpControllerFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.dispatcher.ihttpcontrollerfactory(v=vs.108).aspx) which can be used to generate controllers in custom ways.

However, the System.Web.Http DLL referenced from Visual Studio:
*packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.4.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Http.dll*

Doesn't have that interface:

[image]

**So where is the interface now?**

Answer (score 3):

It's gone and replaced by a [`dependency resolver`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver) or more specifically the [`IDependencyResolver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.dependencies.idependencyresolver%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) interface. Once you write your own dependency resolve you could plug it into the Web API:

```
config.DependencyResolver = new MyDependencyResolver();
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot find it as well.

Anyway you can use IHttpControllerActivator to create your custom controller factories in Web API.