# Dynamic implement service in controller in C# Web Api core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating Type (by reflection) that is extending `ApiController`. How can I dynamically register it (It can be registered at startup, no need to do this at runtime).

Long story: So in my application I have multiple interfaces, i.e.:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
     MyResponse Hello(MyRequest request);
}
```

The thing that I want to achieve is for each interface create controller that should look like this:

```
public class IMyInterfaceController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IMyInterface _MyInterface;
    public IMyInterfaceController (IMyInterface MyInterface)
    {
         _MyInterface=MyInterface;
    }
    
    public MyResponse Hello([FromBody] MyRequest request)
    {
        return MyInterface.Hello(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can generate code using t4 templates at development time and avoid taking a hit on the reflection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic register controller in C# Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813884/dynamic-register-controller-in-c-sharp-web-api)

Comment: @Ramesh this not for core

Comment: In Core - you can do the similar thing in the Startup Class instead of global.asax

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46156649/30594

Comment: The duplicate shows how to register a controller at runtime. Why do you want to do that though? Are you trying to provide some common services to all "interfaces' ? And where would those interfaces come from? If all those controllers have the same behaviour, wouldn't it be better to use a *base class* instead?